# Histogram with stacked percentage for each bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram with the proportion of the class (0/1) for each bin.

I have already plotted a barplot with stacked percentage (image below), but it doesn't look the way I want to.

Stacked percentage barplot

[image: 1]

I want something like this (it was on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008663/plot-stacked-histogram-by-another-group-with-y-axis-as-percentage-proportion), but it is coded in R, I want it in python), and if possible, using the seaborn library:

Stacked percentage histplot

[image: 2]

My dataset is super simple, it contains a column with the age and another one for classification (0/1):

```
df.head()
```

[dataset

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

With seaborn, you can use `sns.histplot(..., multiple='fill')`.

Here is an example starting from the titanic dataset:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.histplot(data=titanic, x='age', hue='alive', multiple='fill', bins=np.arange(0, 91, 10), palette='spring')
for bars in ax.containers:
    heights = [b.get_height() for b in bars]
    labels = [f'{h * 100:.1f}%' if h > 0.001 else '' for h in heights]
    ax.bar_label(bars, labels=labels, label_type='center')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage of age group')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot filling to 100%]

Comment: Looks cool! Thank you for your answer. Also, I was trying to figure out how to write percentages on every group, so another thing solved!